# How to complete gcd number theory proof with induction?

Tags: number-theory, induction, alternative-proof, gcd-and-lcm, prime-factorization

Consider the following proof question: prove for all natural numbers $n$, if $n\mid a$ and $n\mid b$ then $n\mid\gcd(a,b).$

Using the prime factorization of $a, b$ and $\gcd(a,b),$ this proof should be straightforward. Namely, since $n\mid a$ and $n\mid b$, then the prime factorization of $n$ must contain the same primes in $\gcd(a,b),$ since the prime factorization of $\gcd(a,b)$ will contain the minimal number of primes from both $a$ and $b$.

That said, is there a way to do this proof with induction? If so, what would the induction hypothesis ($P(k)$) be and how could I use that to prove the following case ($P(k+1)$) after the inductive hypothesis?

Comment: The induction will not work, if I understand you right. Because there is no known relationship/connection between the prime factors of $n$ and $n+1$.

Comment: @ENV I guess (it's my guess, so you're free to refute the claim) there is no way you can do that using induction as we already take up the general case in the method you've mentioned.

Comment: @lonestudent yes you're right, I guess my argument was weak

Comment: @ENV also the method you've mentioned is even more understandable... one can easily gauge out from the proof why it's all like that

Comment: one may do induction on $k$ with $a+b \leq k\; . $  When $a > b, $ how do $\gcd(a,b) $ and $ \gcd(b,a-b)$ compare?

Comment: The only relevant # that I can think of to induct would be the # of distinct primes that appear in the gcd$(a,b)$.  However, this is pointless, because the direct proof, without induction, is so straightforward.

Comment: @lonestudent would my answer below be sufficient? If this qn is likely to get closed and draw quintillions of downvotes, please notify me.

Answer (score 1):

I guess doing an induction proof for this is really senseless. As from the questions I have tried, induction is very useful when it comes to proving properties or theorems for a continuum of numbers (as in the case of proving the FTA - Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic). Here we aren't considering any continuum - we take two numbers such that they divide a particular number and show that their GCD can also divide the same number. Coming to the FTA, we need to prove that all of the integers are either primes or a product of various powers of various primes, and while doing so we generalize it over a continuum of numbers, thus making the statement hold for all integers. The problem in question is also a generalized property, but we take two arbitrary numbers instead of a whole sequence of them. If you ever try extending this over any number of integers as well, using induction is meaningless as still it's obvious that there always exists a GCD for an arbitrarily taken set of integers and that since all those numbers are expressible as a multiple of this GCD and since they divide the number taken, the GCD also divides the number by Euclid's lemma on divisibility.

A better proof (possibly; I am still a bit weak at proof writing) would be:

---

**Hypothesis**: we need to prove, $(a \mid n) \land(b \mid n) \implies \gcd(a,b) \mid n$

1. If you're going to use the prime factorisation of both the numbers:
   Let $a = \prod\limits_{i=1}^{k}p_i^{m_i}$ and $b = \prod\limits_{i=1}^{l}q_i^{n_i}$ where $p_i,q_i$ are primes and $m_i,n_i$ are respective powers of the $i$th prime if you ever consider their order, but for now let's just generalize it.
   The GCD of $a$ and $b$ will have all the primes common to both $a$ and $b$ since it will divide both $a$ and $b$.
   Notice that since $a \mid n$, by FTA we can say that $ p_i \mid n \space \forall \space p_i \mid a$. The same can be done for $b$ as well.
   Since the GCD will have all primes that are common to both $a$ and $b$, we can, WLOG, assume that $
   \gcd(a,b) = c_1^{r_1}c_2^{r_2}\dots$ where $c_v^{r_v}$ are the common primes raised to their respective common powers. We see that all of the primes of $a$ or $b$ can divide $n$ and these primes are present in the GCD as well, but their powers are $\min(v_{c_V}(a),v_{c_V}(b))$ and is less that $v_{c_v}(n)$ since both $a$ and $b$ can divide $n$. And hence we see that all the primes in the GCD are also present in $n$ and thus we see, $\gcd(a,b) \mid n$ (I guess I have made some loopholes in this proof, so please point them out, if any.)
2. An even easier thing would be to deduce that $a \mid n \implies n = ax$ and $b \mid n \implies n = by$ and since $(\gcd(a,b) \mid a)\land(\gcd(a,b) \mid b)$, $\gcd(a,b) \mid ax$ and $\gcd(a,b)\mid by$ and thus we see $\gcd(a,b) \mid n$. This is, obviously, a rephrasing of the above proof, without having to specifically consider all primes.